# Reasons for preferring listening to "up to date" podcast episodes

Tags: registration, sound

Not sure this makes a good post for this site, but I am looking for use cases which would make the podcasting model still viable in nowadays times in view of the following considerations. I wanted to know, from a usability perspective, what would make a user want to stay up to date and always listen to the latest podcast episode, as opposed to any episode. I ask because I am used to YouTube videos, address usually, i just click on any video I am interested in, and don't care about what date it was published. So, my question is, what makes podcasters care about the episode date? I mean, the only scenario I can think of is if it was about news or politics, in which case users may almost never want to download or stream and listen to old stuff.

Anyone have any other use case ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the podcast and why a user listens.

I listen to several podcasts and there's 2 reasons why I want to stay up to date on a few of them (not all)

1. **Storyline**. Just like a TV show, some podcasts tell a story in progress. Eg I listen to the *Lost Decade Games* podcast all about an indie game developer's "as it happens" process of making games
2. **Great Content / Personalities**. I listen to the *StackExchange* podcast... every episode since the first one back when it was the Jeff/Joel *StackOverflow* podcast.

There are others I listen to, but without commitment to listen to every one.

For me, when I discovered the game dev podcast and realized I liked it, I went back 100+ episodes and started listening from the beginning.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply.I've searched from the "Pocket Casts" podcast app, but all I was able to find was the "Skeptics SE Podcast", I couldn't find other SE our a generic SE Podcast. Would you be able to tell me how choke I couldn't find them?

Comment: How do podcast clients (dispatchers) search for podcasts? Is there one our mute central servers somewhere that can be queried for a list of podcast streams? How does the technology work?

Comment: The StackExchange podcast can be found using this RSS feed: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/feed/podcast/ but every podcast is different, to get better promotion many podcasters will submit their feeds to iTunes/Google Play so they can easily be found in default apps on iOS and Android.

Comment: So podcasters update their podcast to the server of every podcatcher out there to gain recognition? Seems strange that there would not be a central server.

Comment: What format is the URL you gave me for the podcast? Are there different formats for the files in podcast URLs, and what are these? Finally, could do I just paste the URL into my podcast client to use it. Can you please post a screenshot? When I open the intent the podcast client I have installed does not show up add a receiver on my Android device. Thanks.